# Can't stay signed in to Game Center for more than 10 minutes

Tags: ipad, game-center

Every time I sign in to the Game Center via my iPad's Settings, my profile window won't close. Ten minutes later I am no longer signed in to Game Center and have to do it all again. As a result my games' contents are not updating and I lose game progress. (especially in Sims Freeplay) Recurring problem since 6 July 2014.